# How do I configure the plan yaml file to send the hostname to the dhcp server?

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan

I'm moving from raspian to ubuntu.  On raspian, the dhcpcd.conf file could contain the line:
hostname  "foobar"
which would send "foobar" to the dhcp server as the hostname.  Very convenient on a home network when looking at router connections list on the dhcp server.

I can't seem to find the equivalent with netplan.  There is documentation for send-hostname & hostname, but I am likely doing something wrong:

> Blockquote

```
     eth0:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: 
           - 192.168.1.52/24
        gateway4: 192.168.1.254
        nameservers:  
            addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
        dhcp4-overrides:
           send-hostname: true
           hostname: "rpi4-8g"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your netplan yaml shows that you have configured the `dhcp4-overrides` correctly, but you have also told netplan not to use DHCP at all, but instead use static addresses.  `dhcp4: yes` should have the correct effect.